# Adding disc brake to a bike without rear disc brake mounts

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, hybrid-bike

I'm seeking advice on how to install disc brakes on a bike that does not have rear disc brake mounts. The bike I have is the Trek 7.1 FX.

Does the Trek 7.1 FX have the mount for installing disc brakes?

Which disc brake option is better to go for, mechanical or hydraulic?

Which brands are reliable, or does Trek provides some custom kit?

Comment: No, not mentioned in the specs, and no visible mount points in the pictures.  Adding disc brakes would be ill-advised.

Comment: @DanielRHicks can you explain why it will be ill advised? except economical point of view

Comment: Aluminum frame, no mounting bosses, meaning you'd have strength/stress issues with the frame.  Maybe that Brake Therapy thing discussed below would work on the rear, but otherwise you'd have a bit of a mess.

Comment: @DanielRHicks agreed. but wondering the trex 7.3 fx has a disc brake option available, maybe the fork can do the work for front. But already convinced that its really not worth doing so. Thanks for advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like that bike includes the caliper mounts, and the wheels hubs do not have rotor mounts.

Converting a bike like this to disc brakes would require custom frame work, a new fork and new wheels (or at least new hubs and a wheel build).  From a financial standpoint it makes a lot more sense to buy a bike already equipped with disc brakes.

This [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/4203/213) covers the pros and cons for different braking systems.

**EDIT** I stand corrected on the issue of 'required frame work' as @cbamber85 mentions below, there is a product called [Brake Therapy Conversion Kit](http://2btherapy.com/bikes/brake-therapy-conversion-kit) available that will allow you to mount disc brakes on your rear triangle.  Looks like the cost is about $150 USD and you would still need new hubs.

Comment: You wouldn't need custom frame work, back in the day I used to have a Brake Therapy converter.  It was a disc mount that had a long arm that latched onto your v-brake mount, and the other end was special hub cap. Worked great.

Comment: @cbamber85 True - I never really considered using one, but I have edited the answer to include info about the kit.

Comment: wow great info, i was going to ask is it really worth to add disc brakes to Trek 7.1 Fx but thankfully you already answered it.

Comment: There are a few different types of adapters, though they are now getting harder to find. The A2Z DM-UNI is another option, about £25. http://www.wiggle.co.uk/a2z-universal-disc-mount/
It will depend on the dropouts as to whether it fits.