# What kind of frame and brakes are these?

Tags: brakes, frames

I just bought a bike and I can't figure out what kind of frame and brakes it has.

I found that the derailleurs were made by DNB Japan somewhere around 1960 and that the handlebar is french (Guidonn Phillipe), but other than that , this bike is a mystery to me.

The brakes only have a logo on them and the frame has only a number and a logo on the back. Underneath all the black paint, in the front, is a sticker but there is no way I can peel just the paint without damaging the sticker...

I would love to know what frame I am dealing with because the bike (even though it has seen better days) works great and I would like to take a shot at restoring it.[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Dunno - but given the apparent age, don't expect that all the parts are original.  Those pedals (MKS brand?) look more recent, and the handlebars may not be original either - I'd have expected drop bars.   Its a lovely looking lugged bike and definitely worth looking after.

Comment: There's a good answer here about different brake types: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8806/26481